# How to set multiple numbers to their absolute value in C more concisely?

Tags: c, if-statement, simplify

How can I simplify those three simple if conditions?

```c
if(v.x < 0)
{
    v.x *= -1;
}
if(v.y < 0)
{
    v.y *= -1;
}
if(v.z < 0)
{
    v.z *= -1;
}
```

Comment: think What do you think this code does (btw, not sure if it can be "simplified". But it can be rewritten in a more concise form)?

Comment: If `v.x, v.y, v.z` are `unsigned`, code can be simplified to `;`  ;-)

Answer (score 11):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
v.x = abs(v.x);
v.y = abs(v.y);
v.z = abs(v.z);
```

Or `labs`, `llabs`, `fabs` (`<math.h>`), etc. depending of type of your numbers.

Comment: The `abs()` family of functions only require stdlib.h, not math.h

Comment: @user3629249 even fabs ?

Comment: the `abs()` family of functions are only about integral types.    the `fabs()` family of functions are about floats and doubles so is not part of the `abs()` family of functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
v.x = (v.x < 0) ? (v.x * -1) : (v.x) ;
v.y = (v.y < 0) ? (v.y * -1) : (v.y) ;
v.z = (v.z < 0) ? (v.z * -1) : (v.z) ;
```

This uses the C [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).